# How to scan for integers in a line that has already been scanned with scan.nextLine()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to write a method that scans a text file and adds all lines that start with `#` to a `String` called metadata. After that I want to scan the next three integers, starting in the first line that does not contain a `#`. However, the first line that does not contain a `#` gets skipped because I already used `scan.nextLine()` to scan it.

```
File file = new File(filename);
Scanner scan  = new Scanner(file);

String format = scan.nextLine();
String metadata = "";

//This loop adds all lines starting with # to metadata.
outerloop:
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scan.nextLine();
    if(line.startsWith("#")){
        metadata = metadata+line;
    } else {
        break outerloop;
    }
}

//Scans the next three integers and sets them equal to width, height, and maxRange.
int width = scan.nextInt();
int height = scan.nextInt();
int maxRange = scan.nextInt();
```

My input is a text file. The first six lines are shown in this screenshot.

[image: screenshot]

There is only one line starting with #, however my method has to be able to handle a file with multiple lines starting with #. The output should be

```
format = "P3"  
metadata = "# CREATOR: GIMP PNM Filter Version 1.1"  
width = 200  
height = 133  
maxRange = 255
```

However instead I get

```
format = "P3"  
metadata = "# CREATOR: GIMP PNM Filter Version 1.1"  
width = 255 
height = 183
maxRange = 187
```

Comment: show us as a comment what is the input and the expected output please...

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner-java.lang.String-

Comment: You could make `new Scanner(line)`

Comment: I edited my answer and gave you working code.

Comment: Thanks @cricket_007, I tried that and it's working now :)

Answer (score 1):

Your line is a String. You can search for all substrings matching the following regex:

```
[0-9]+
```

This can be done in a following way:

```
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+")
                   .matcher(readLineWhichIsString);
while (m.find()) {
   matches.add(m.group());
}

int[] numbersInLine = new int[matches.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    numbersInLine[i] = Integer.parseInt(matches.get(i));
}
```

The above solution will match `12` from `12a`. If you don't want it, just change the regex. I'll make some research for you.

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+(?=\\s|$)")
```

will only match those `String`s that are digits followed by a space or end of `String`.

**Edit:**
The below code will fill `int[] values` with your `int` parameters.

```
String line;
while(scan.hasNextLine()){
    line = scan.nextLine();
    if(line.startsWith("#")){
      metadata = metadata+line;
    }else{
      break outerloop;
    }
}

int[] values = new int[3];
List<String> matches = new ArrayList<>();
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[0-9]+(?=\\s|$)")
               .matcher(readLineWhichIsString);
while (m.find()) {
   matches.add(m.group());
}

int i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < Math.min(matches.size(), values.length); i++) {
    numbersInLine[i] = Integer.parseInt(matches.get(i));
}
while (i < 3) {
    values[i] = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, ended up using new Scanner(line) instead because it was simpler.

Comment: @MeghanWhite anyway recommend you trying my solution too, as it might be helpful one day.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in logic when you check for # in line and it is not you want to read that line again

here is a proposed solution

```
  //This loop adds all lines starting with # to metadata.
  String line = null;
  while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
     line = scanner.nextLine();
    if(line.startsWith("#")){
      metadata = metadata+line;
    }else{
      break ;
    }
  }

  //Scans the next three integers and sets them equal to width, height, and maxRange.
  String ints[]=line.split(" ");
  int width = Integer.parseInt(ints[0]);
  int height = Integer.parseInt(ints[1]);
  int maxRange = scanner.nextInt();
```

This works and you get desired reuslt
and why to re read a file when you have the line already